# Python CSV Writer only writing last item processed

Tags: python

I am looping through a CSV and creating a new one in 'python3' like this...

```
for row in csvreader:

    with open('employee_file.csv', mode='w', encoding='utf-8') as employee_file:

        employee_writer = csv.writer(employee_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        employee_writer.writerow([row[0],employeeName])
```

But once it finished processing I am left with only the last result in employee_file.csv. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You should append to the file instead of writing into it. Change the mode to `a` (append). Cheers!

Comment: You are also opening employee_file.csv for each row written from csvreader. Is that your intent? Or, do you want to open the output file and write many rows in succession?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the file opening line before the for loop. The way you have it now you keep writing it over in the for loop.

```
with open('employee_file.csv', mode='w', encoding='utf-8') as employee_file:
   for row in csvreader:
        ...
```

Comment: @fightstarr20 You'll want your csv.writer() line between the with... and your for loop and the writerow() statement in the loop.